# How can I figure out specific app is running on Xmonad?

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmobar

I don't like the behavior of default toggle of xmobar.
So I decided to make my own toggle.

```
toggleXmobar :: X ()
toggleXmobar = do
  isRunning <- isApplicationRunning "xmobar"
  if isRunning
    then spawn "pkill xmobar"
    else spawn "xmobar"

isApplicationRunning :: String -> X Bool
isApplicationRunning appName = do
  ws <- gets windowset
  let wins = allWindows ws
  anyM (runQuery (className =? appName)) wins

anyM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m Bool
anyM _ [] = return False
anyM p (x : xs) = do
  result <- p x
  if result then return True else anyM p xs
```

Hard point is `isApplicationRunning`.
It always say that xmobar is not running.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Folks typically configure xmonad to ignore docks (which are defined as windows that define some specific atom that I don't remember off the top of my head), and xmobar registers itself as a dock. That is why it will not be in xmonad's list of windows. You may need to manually make X calls to peruse the window tree, use `pgrep` or similar, or manually track PIDs when you spawn `xmobar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation for the behavior you're seeing is that xmobar registers itself as a dock, and you have configured xmonad to ignore docks.

One way around would be to manually traverse the window tree. You can use [`asks display`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.2/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:display) or [`withDisplay`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.2/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:withDisplay) to retrieve the X connection, [`screenCount`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11-1.10.3/docs/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Display.html#v:screenCount) to determine how many screens there are, [`rootWindow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11-1.10.3/docs/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Display.html#v:rootWindow) to retrieve the root for each screen, and [`queryTree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11-1.10.3/docs/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Extras.html#v:queryTree) to peruse the children (recursively, presumably).

It's possible there's something in xmonad already to help with this, I'm not sure.